# trash:/// in Linux Mint does not correspond with ~/.local/share/Trash/files/

Tags: linux-mint, trash

When I use Bleachbit to empty the system trash, it removes all the files from ~/.local/share/Trash/files/ alright, but when I click on the trash icon on the desktop in Linux Mint (with path trash:/// in Nautilus), I still have a lot of trashed files as if it were another trash somewhere in the system. Can someone explain this to me?

By the way, I close Nautilus after running Bleachbit to make sure it wasn't a refresh issue.

Comment: This sounds like a bug you'd better report.

Comment: I don't think so. When I search the location of the trash in Linux on the Internet, I found out that it was at ~/.local/share/Trash. So, it suggests to me that Bleachbit is doing it right, no?